# Regexpquery in lucene not working

Tags: java, lucene

I am using lucene 5.4 to search some texts from a file using regex, but regexpquery is not working, despite phrasequery and normal queries are working and able to find file with the occurance of searched string, but when i am running regex query,lucenece doesnt find any file containing that regex.

Index creation code:

```
public IndexWriter generateIndex(String docsPath) throws IOException {

      String indexPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") +File.separator+"indexDirectory";
        if (indexPath == null) {
          throw new IOException("System property 'java.io.tmpdir' does not specify a tmp dir");
        }
        File tmpDir = new File(indexPath);
        if (!tmpDir.exists()) {
          boolean created = tmpDir.mkdirs();
          if (!created) {
            throw new IOException("Unable to create tmp dir " + tmpDir);
          }
        }

    boolean create = true;
    final Path docDir = Paths.get(docsPath);
    if (!Files.isReadable(docDir)) {
        System.out.println("Document directory '" + docDir.toAbsolutePath()
                + "' does not exist or is not readable, please check the path");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Date start = new Date();
    try {
        System.out.println("Indexing to directory '" + indexPath + "'...");

        Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(indexPath));
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
        IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);

        if (create) {
            iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
        } else {
            iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
        }

        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);
        indexDocs(writer, docDir);
        setIndexWriter(writer);

        Date end = new Date();
        System.out.println(end.getTime() - start.getTime() + " total milliseconds");
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(" caught a " + e.getClass() + "\n with message: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return getIndexWriter();
}

static void indexDocs(final IndexWriter writer, Path path) throws IOException {
    if (Files.isDirectory(path)) {
        Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                try {
                    indexDoc(writer, file, attrs.lastModifiedTime().toMillis());
                } catch (IOException ignore) {
                    // don't index files that can't be read.
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    } else {
        indexDoc(writer, path, Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).toMillis());
    }
}
static void indexDoc(IndexWriter writer, Path file, long lastModified) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream stream = Files.newInputStream(file)) {
        Document doc = new Document();
        Field pathField = new StringField("path", file.toString(), Field.Store.YES);
        doc.add(pathField);

        doc.add(new LongField("modified", lastModified, Field.Store.NO));
        doc.add(new TextField("contents",
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));

        if (writer.getConfig().getOpenMode() == OpenMode.CREATE) {
            System.out.println("adding " + file);
            writer.addDocument(doc);
        } else {
            System.out.println("updating " + file);
            writer.updateDocument(new Term("path", file.toString()), doc);
        }
    }
}
```

Searching a text with regex code:

```
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(index)));
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();

    BufferedReader in = null;

    Query query = new RegexpQuery(new Term("contents", "program-id\\."));
    query = query.rewrite(reader);

    System.out.println("Searching for: " + query.toString(field));
    searcher.search(query, null, 100);
```

Query parser code which is working:

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(field, analyzer);
Query query = parser.parse("+program-id");
```

Source Code on which we will search:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID.  ACINSTAL.

   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.

   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
```

Please help.

Comment: And what exactly does "not working" mean? Does it throw an exception? What the exception message is? Does it produce a wrong/unexpected result? What result does it produce? What is the expected result? You are more likely to get help if you edit your question according to [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your RegexpQuery allows whitespace. Your code does not contain your IndexWriterConfig (nor an example file). Be aware that a solr query matches against the generated tokens in the inverted index. Typically there is no whitespace in this tokens.

Comment: @KarstenR. I have updated complete source code and example file code, where i will search. please look into it.

Comment: StandardAnalyzer will remove not only whitespace but also you dots. RegexprQuery does not use an analyzer: you try to find a token "program-id." but there is only "program-id." --> no hit

Comment: @KarstenR.  "enviro.*division"
this regex neither have spaces nor have dots, but its also not working

Comment: The RegexprQuery must match !one! token. Your example would match "ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.". With StandardAnalyzer this goes to !two! tokens.

Comment: @KarstenR. Thanks for the valuable information. Is there a way to match more than one token?

Comment: The RegexpQuery is like TermQuery: A match will correspond to one token. (But you could e.g. use every whole line as token)

Comment: @KarstenR. can you please share sample code for using every line as a token??

Comment: Tokenizer which can be configured to split at new line: https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/pattern/PatternTokenizer.html

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments, a regex query must match a single token.  There is no query type that allows you to have a single regex spanning multiple terms.  Regex queries, in my opinion, should generally be avoided on full-text content (if the field is a simple identifier, or some such, that's a different story).  If you are using them, it might be an indication that you are failing to provide an *effective* full-text search.  You should favor using more typical full text search tools when available, such as wildcard, fuzzy, proximity and range queries, or tuning your analysis to provide more useful search results.

However, if you insist on it, there are two ways to approach supporting this sort of search.

1. You can change your analysis to tokenize in a way that supports your search needs.  Using a `StringField` will create a single token, so regex queries will work more as you expect.  Of course, this will tend toward poor performance, and will have much poorer support of more standard styles of query.  If the field is a string identifier of some sort, this is probably the best solution.  If it is a full text field that you want to have robust full text search support, it is almost certainly an awful solution.
2. You can use a query that makes more sense for the situation.  In the example you've provided, a simple phrase query does the job just fine, as you've indicated yourself, so it's difficult to say what you would need here.  Generally for complex regex queries spanning multiple terms, you would have to support it using the [`SpanQuery`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanQuery.html) API, usually multiple [`SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper.html) combined using [`SpanNearQuery`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanNearQuery.html).

   Also, worth noting, the [SurroundQueryParser](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/surround/parser/QueryParser.html) is available, which is designed to work with the `SpanQuery` api.  It doesn't support regex, but if wildcard queries combined into phrases with SpanNears ends up being what you need, that QueryParser may prove a handy tool.